# document.getElementById not working with Google data studio embeded

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed, looker-studio

I'm using this code to change dynamically the iframe URL and it works well when I'm using "https://www.icqmail.com/" URL but when I using this URL "https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/1se-9ZRSukdgQUiRqYTSjT8nFLTV0v8Uq/page/y5MR" data studio embedded I got 404.

When I changed the iframe src to be equal to URL like this `src="https://www.icqmail.com/"` both sites are working well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="https://assets-cdn.github.com/pinned-octocat.svg" color="#000000">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://assets-cdn.github.com/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://assets-cdn.github.com/favicon.ico">
      
    <style> 
        body { background: #232323; width: 95%; margin: 0 auto; }
        
        /* Responsive Container for iFrame */
        .embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } 
        .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>
    
    <title>Tech Ops PH | your &lt; IT / design &lt; partner </title>
  <script type="text/javascript">


   
    window.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (event.data) {
      
     document.getElementById("myIframe").src=decodeURI(event.data)

console.log(decodeURI(event.data));
      
    }
  
 }

</script>
  
</head>

<body>
    <div class='embed-container embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3'>
            <iframe  id="myIframe" width="600" height="9000"  frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Why the `document.getElementById("myIframe").src` code doesn't work well with "https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/1se-9ZRSukdgQUiRqYTSjT8nFLTV0v8Uq/page/y5MR" and work well with "https://www.icqmail.com/" how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Via response headers web pages can tell the browser what other pages are allowed to iframe them.

Eg. datastudio.google.com sends the header:
`x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN`
Meaning "The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself."
[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

But your other page does not so it can be embedded.

Comment: So there is something I can do to use the data studio URL on my side?

Comment: You're not going to be able to load the google site in an iframe on any major browser without modifying it. This is a security feature not a defect. If you tell me what your end goal is perhaps I can make an alternative suggestion.

Comment: But this URL create for embedded purposes, why does `src=https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/1se-9ZRSukdgQUiRqYTSjT8nFLTV0v8Uq/page/y5MR` work well? and `document.getElementById("myIframe").src =https://datastudio.google.c...` not work,  what is the difference?